# Determine duplicate data's

Tags: filter, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-conditional-formatting

I have 3 columns and i'm trying to determine duplicates in column Items and column QTY by highlighting the duplicate data

Example.
For every employee required to have 1 pencil & 1 bag only. 
If there is duplicate data of items or the QTY is exceed to required number of PENCIL & BAG it will highlight with color.

Is this possible? Please help me!

```
*---*----*---*--------------*
| EMPLOYEE  | ITEMS    | QTY|
*-----------*-------  -*----*
| MICHAEL   | PAPER     | 1 |
| MICHAEL   | PEN       | 1 |
| MICHAEL   | bag       | 2 |
| MICHAEL   | pencil    | 1 |
| MICHAEL   | pencil    | 1 |
*---*----*-----------------*
```

This is the formula i tried.

```
 =AND(OR(B2="PENCIL",B2="BAG"),COUNTIF(C,D>2),A2)<>VALUE(B2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add helper column with formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A), REGEXREPLACE(""& 
 N(REGEXMATCH(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A2:C),,999^99)), 
 TEXTJOIN("|",1,TRIM(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({QUERY(A2:C, 
 "where lower(B) matches 'bag|pencil' and C>1", 0);
 QUERY(FILTER(A2:C, COUNTIF(A2:A&B2:B, A2:A&B2:B)>1), 
 "where lower(Col2) matches 'bag|pencil'", 0)})
 ,,999^99))))))), "^0$", ), ))
```

[image: 0]

then use conditional formatting:

```
=IF($F2="1",1)
```

[image: 0]

## [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cWQrphBRIOIFV9cHwz-U3LH9OFDK8Eouxez-dM1_ARI/copy)

Comment: Sir when i try to add new employee then add pencil, it highlighted the rows even though I did not put value in QTY

Comment: well QTY is kinda required but you can try to change `IF(LEN(A2:A)` to `IF(LEN(C2:C)`

Comment: Sir the result is the same.

Comment: Here's the link sir [Google Sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wS6jQMERnSOOvsVIsVkOkX6wGbrkn5x7Yz-vbVvULwo/copy).

Comment: @Kny answer updated - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fu1ln1x-OCkCc6WPcTo-tpgJySfNiaahDWJZqcyBPw0/edit#gid=0 - https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiRak.png

Comment: Sir @player0 when i have a lot of data, i get this error. In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows.

Comment: can you share a copy of such sheet?

Comment: Here's the link sir [Google sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wS6jQMERnSOOvsVIsVkOkX6wGbrkn5x7Yz-vbVvULwo/copy).

Comment: use this fixed formula: `=ARRAYFORMULA({""; IF(LEN(B2:B), REGEXREPLACE(""& 
 N(REGEXMATCH(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B2:D),,999^99)), 
 TEXTJOIN("|",1,TRIM(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({IFERROR(QUERY(B2:D, 
 "where lower(C) matches 'bag|pencil' and D>1", 0),  {"♥","♥","♥"});
 IFERROR(QUERY(FILTER(B2:D, COUNTIF(B2:B&C2:C,B2:B&C2:C)>1), 
 "where lower(Col2) matches 'bag|pencil'", 0), {"♥","♥","♥"})})
 ,,999^99))))))), "^0$", ), )})` and format column D as number - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FPCjtLntAJxHXSjXrVA1sFRQU4TbXIlzO3tS-GzTik8/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

If I did get your question correctly, I believe one possible way to achieve what you need is to put this formula in the conditional formatting config:

```
=index(query($A:$C,"select sum(C) where A='"&$A1&"' and B='"&$B1&"'",0),2,1)>1
```

(assuming your data are in columns A:C, else change accordingly).

Comment: not working like in "doing nothing", or like in "not addressing your need? In my case, based on your data, the last 3 rows were highlighted. What would be your expected result, if different? I may have misunderstood the question.